# Detail in a theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

So, I am interested in John Conway, Complex Analysis volume 1 page 125, theorem 3.8 (Rouche's theorem), http://keats.kcl.ac.uk/pluginfile.php/1130890/mod_resource/content/1/Conway%20J%20--%20Functions%20of%20One%20Complex%20Variable.pdf
is a direct link to the book. So, he claims this thing: $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}[\frac{f'}{f}-\frac{g'}{g}] = (Z(f)-P(f))-(Z(g)-P(g))$ but this is equivalent(if I am not wrong) to $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{f'}{f} = Z(f)-P(f)$, then applying the same for g. But how to get $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{f'}{f} = Z(f)-P(f)$??

Comment: Was the residue theorem proved before that in Conway's book?

Comment: Yes, of course, Daniel.

Comment: In that case, just determine the residues of $\frac{f'}{f}$. If $f(z) = (z-z_0)^k\cdot g(z)$ with $g(z_0) \in \mathbb{C}^\ast$, then $\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{f'}{f}; z_0\right) = k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He used the argument principle (on page 123) to get $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f'}{f} = Z(f) - P(f)$.

Comment: That is clear. But how did he get it?? I don't see....

Comment: @nikola his $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve which contains all the zeros and poles of $f$, so the winding numbers about each zero and pole of $f$ is equal to $1$. Therefore, the sum the winding numbers of $f$ about the zeros of $f$ equals $Z(f)$ and the sum of the winding numbers of $f$ about the poles of $f$ is $P(f)$. Then by the argument principle, $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f'}{f}\, dz = Z(f) - P(f)$.

Comment: but, you use this(as I see)  $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve, so the winding numbers about each zero and pole of f is equal to 1. Why that??

Comment: @nikola since the zeros and poles of $f$ lie inside $\gamma$, the winding numbers about each zero and pole of $f$ equals $1$.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have figured out why, thanks to kobe and to Daniel Fischer. So,

According to the argument principle, this thing is a $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z-z_k}$ for zeros, where $z_k$ is a zero. So, we want this integral. Function $\frac{1}{z-z_k}$ has a isolated singularity $z_k$, which is a pole of order 1. So, our function is $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ so we have a formula that for first order pole x residuum is $\frac{f(x)}{g'(x)}$. But, as $g(x) = x - z_k$ it implies that $g'(x) = 1$ and as $f(x) = 1$ we have a reziduum 1 for each zero. Now, for each zero the worth of each integral is $2 \pi i$, so the total worth of sum is $2\pi i Z(f)$ but we have divizion with $2 \pi i$ in front of the sum which gives us Z(f). Same with the poles. Did I make it??